# Entity Framework many-to-many relationship adding one object to the referenced class causes duplication

Tags: c#, oop, entity-framework-core, primary-key

I have movie and actor classes which have a many-to-many relationship. On updating movies I want to add the actors to the movies, remove the actors and update actors in one go but it doesn't work.

```
public async Task UpdateMovieAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, MovieRequestPutModel movie)
{
    var movieToUpdate = await _unitOfWork.Movie.GetMovieById(movie.Id, cancellationToken) ?? throw new Exception("Not Found");

    // Update the movie properties.
    movie.Adapt(movieToUpdate);

    var test = await _unitOfWork.Movie.GetMovieById(movie.Id, cancellationToken) ?? throw new Exception("Not Found"); 
    movieToUpdate.ModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;

    // Update the movie's actors.
    movieToUpdate.Actors.Clear(); // remove all existing actors

    foreach (var actor in movie.Actors)
    {
        // Retrieve the existing actor from the context (if it exists).
        var existingActor = await _unitOfWork.Actor.GetActorById(actor.Id, cancellationToken);

        if (existingActor != null)
        {
            // Update the existing actor's properties.
            actor.Adapt(existingActor);
            test = await _unitOfWork.Movie.GetMovieById(movie.Id, cancellationToken) ?? throw new Exception("Not Found");
            var actorToAdd = new Actor { Id = existingActor.Id, Name = existingActor.Name, Img = existingActor.Img };

            // Add the existing actor to the movie's actors.
            movieToUpdate.Actors.Add(actorToAdd);
            test = await _unitOfWork.Movie.GetMovieById(movie.Id, cancellationToken) ?? throw new Exception("Not Found"); 
        }
    }

    _unitOfWork.Save();
}
```

Where I add actors with the add method it inserts 2 actors with the same key instead of one.

I tried debugging and unexpected things happened. If I add to actor once and use the `_context.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList()` method in quickwatch evaluate it, the tracked object of movie has 2 actors instead of one. When I check the movieToUpdate variable it also has 2 actors. But if I don't check it in quickwatch then movieToUpdate has 1 actor but in the end after `_context.SaveChanges()` I get an error:

> The instance of entity type 'Actor' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values

What could be the cause and how I should've done it?

I use test variable for checking context.

This is my GetMovieById method where I get Movie with nested Actors:

```cs
public async Task<Movie> GetMovieById(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await _dbSet.Where(x => x.Id == id).Include(x => x.Actors).SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
```

And this is my GetActoryById method:

````cs
 public async Task<Actor> GetActorById(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await _dbSet.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id, cancellationToken);
        }
    ```
````

Comment: Does existingActor have a navigation property for Movies that is being populated? If so, you might be adding the actor to the movie object when you're calling actor.Adapt(existingActor); which would explain the duped behavior.

Comment: existingActor does have navigation property but it's null because I retrieve it without .inlude() method, movie is retrieved using include(). after calling actor.Adapt(existingActor); I checked context and tracked movie object had 0 count of actors after that so I guess it is not the cause.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.